# how to validate input id is equal to input data in html?

Tags: php, html

i am fresher. can we validate data in input form where id=entered data. if the data is wrong it should change color of the form. with out J query, java script, ajax.

Comment: No you can't do it. w/o JS

Comment: html5 has some limited validation via new input types, but they are not supported the same across browsers. You will need javascript, or perform a full post (page refresh) and validate in php

Comment: @newboyhun PHP can't check the form data anymore? That's very sad :(. Some years ago it was possible ...

Comment: The value of the id attribute is not transferred to the server during a POST operation, therefor PHP cannot compare it to the value.  Only the name (key) and value (value) come through in $_POST.

Comment: @Pagerange Oh, you're right, he wrote `id=...`. That looks like bad form generation. But that wasn't his question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can* use HTML5 to validate data, **however** it is recommended to use for example a jQuery validation since not all browsers support HTML5 validation.

For example you could use this as a very simplified URL-validator,

```
<input type="url" name="website" required pattern="https?://.+">
```

You use HTML5, jQuery, Java Script etc on the CLIENT SIDE when you want to validate something. PHP on the other hand you would use to verify the form data on the SERVER SIDE, that is, when the data has been submitted to your form's action page.